# kendo ui listview with angular - selectable items

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a kendo ui **ListView** and I would like to make the items selectable (single selection). I haven't found any sample on the internet with angular.

What I have to do is to set a style for the selected item and also do some calls based on the selected item.

This is my **HTML**:

```
            <div class="list-group no-radius no-border no-bg m-b-none"
                 kendo-list-view="publishPositionsListView"
                 k-options="ctrl.publishPositionsSourceOptions"
                 k-data-source="ctrl.publishPositionsSource">

                <a class="list-group-item p-l hover-anchor b-a no-select ng-scope" k-template>
                    <span>{{dataItem.Title}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

This is my **JavaScript**:

```
vm.publishPositionsSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    dataType: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "publish/getall",
            type: "GET"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        type: "json",
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total",
        model: {
            id: "Id"
        }
    }
});

vm.publishPositionsSourceOptions = {
    dataBound: function (e) {
        // Set selected style for the first item when loaded
        e.sender.element.children().first().addClass("focus");
    }
}
```

Any idea? I wonder if there is a way of doing that instead of using `ng-click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enabled single selection on a kendoUI listview, add `selectable: "Single"` to your listview-config. 
You can also set the selected item programmatically by using the listview's `select` method.

When you put it all together it might look like this:

```
$scope.listViewOptions = {
    dataSource: $scope.myDataSource,
    selectable: "Single",
    dataBound: function(event) {
        /* Select the first item here */
    },
    change: function(event) {
        /* Do something with the selected item */
    }
}
```

I've also created a working [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJoXI/3) (it's not using angular though).

Comment: How do I get a selected item?

Comment: I did this and I don't get the selected item...instead "e" brings me the sender which is the container. I suppose I need to look for a css class or something like that?

Comment: You can get the current selection via the `select` method and then convert it with the `dataItem` method.
So in the change method you could do something like `event.sender.dataItem(event.sender.select())`.

Regarding styles kendoUI automatically adds the class `k-state-selected` to the currently selected item.